# Operações soma e multiplicação dos números inteiro na lista de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

O código de lista precisa receber 5 cinco números na ordem inversa, meu código faz isso só que **meu código precisa que o 2º número digitado seja multiplicado por 3 e o 4º número seja somado por 5** (lembrando que existe a indexação por zero então é **elemento 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4**).

Essa parte é só um exemplo da resposta desejada:

```
Entrada = [5, 15, 25, 35, 45]
Saída = [50, 35, 25, 45, 5]
```

Por enquanto meu código está assim (mostra os elementos invertidos):

```
elements = input("Enter only 5 numbers: ")

list = elements.split()

inverse_list = list[::-1]

print (inverse_list)
```

Comment: Você está somando 5 ao 5º número.

Comment: Mais é exatamente isso, lembre que o 5º número vai ser o 4º número e o 1º número vai ser o 0º número

Comment: Por causa da indexação por zero muito comum nas linguagens de programação, entende?

Comment: Lembrando que a lista vai exibir o resultado na ordem inversa

Comment: E como você tentou fazer a multiplicação/adição dos valores?

Comment: Esse é o problema, não consigo selecionar o elemento e soma-lo/multiplica-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim:

```
elements = input("Enter only 5 numbers: ")
list = elements.split()

# Acresente essa linha
list[1], list[4] = int(list[1])*3, int(list[4])+5

inverse_list = list[::-1]
print (inverse_list)
```

Saída para o exemplo dado:

```
[50, '35', '25', 45, '5']
```

Comment: como faz o resultado ficar assim `[50, 35, 25, 45, 5] `?

Comment: Deixa consegui consertar, obrigado pela explicação.

Answer (score 1):

Tu estudou sobre arrays? Dá uma olhada [aqui!](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp)

Primeira coisa que tu precisa fazer é converter tua lista para int

```
results = list(map(int, elements.split(',')))
```

Depois tu consegue pegar os valores do array pelo index. Tu pode fazer isso manualmente ou de forma dinâmica.

```
results[1] = results[1] * 3
results[4] = results[4] + 5
```

Depois é só inverter.

```
inverse_list = results[::-1]
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Sim, mais tinha visto arrays em linguagem C

Comment: Muito obrigado, demorei um pouco pra entender pois começou a dar uns erros, mas consegui.